# Subgroup of prime index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a solvable group and $p$ is a prime such that $p\mid |G|$. Does there exist a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $[G:H]=p$ ?

Comment: @DougM No, it's not. The Sylow theorem says that if $p^n$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$, there is a subgroup of order $p^n$.

Comment: @DougM: I think you're confusing the order of $H$ with its index.

Comment: @carmichael561 I see where I am losing it.  Thanks.

Comment: What is true, however, is that the group will have a subgroup whose index is the order of a $p$-Sylow subgroup. Unlike the Sylow theorems this requires the solvability of the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not generally true.  For instance $A_4$ is solvable with $|A_4|=12$ but does not have a subgroup of order 6 = 12/2.

Comment: 6 isn't prime..

Comment: @DougM 2 is the prime in question, $|A_4:H| = 2$ implies $|H| = 6$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I see my error now.